# Improving turn around time when building Java EE apps

Tags: build-process, jakarta-ee

One troubling aspect of building Java EE applications is the turn around time for the edit, compile, deploy process. I tried using Jetty but even that has some problems after making several edits you will usually run into a memory error.

At the moment I use Netbeans and I can see edits to the presentation layer without redeployment but when making changes to the model then a full rebuild is necessary and there could be some problems.

What are some recommendations for improving this aspect of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubling?  Really?  How long are your projects?

I think that Spring dm Server might start making in-roads with its OSGi technology.  It keeps deployments modular, and you can hot deploy/undeploy individual modules.

Comment: I will have to investigate this further. If you can redeploy your application umpteen times without PermGen error then its worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [JavaRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/javarebel/)